# Multiple instances of the same activity open

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has a screen that refreshes every second in AsyncTask:

```
class BarRefresh extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // doSomething();
        while(redraw){
            for(int i = 0; i < c.sets.size(); i++)
            {
                vals[i] = c.sets.get(i).getLast();
            }
            graph.updateVals(vals);
            graph.postInvalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

A click on one of the objects opens a new activity with a parameter:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float[] coords = new float[2];
            coords[0] = ev.getX();
            coords[1] = ev.getY();
            int set = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < graph.values.length; i++){
                if(graph.rects[i].contains(coords[0], coords[1]))
                {
                    redraw = false;
                    Bundle chosen = new Bundle();
                    chosen.putInt("set", i);
                    Intent bb = new Intent(GraphTestActivity.this, LineGraphActivity.class);
                    bb.putExtras(chosen);
                    startActivity(bb);
                //  set = i;
                }
            }
            //Toast t = Toast.makeText(GraphTestActivity.this, "KLIKNIETO " + set, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //t.show();
            return false;
        }
```

In the new activity constructor looks like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle pick = getIntent().getExtras();
    setNr = pick.getInt("set");
    c = Common.getInstance();
    set = c.sets.get(setNr);
    graph = new LineGraph(LineGraphActivity.this, set);
    setContentView(graph);
}
```

Here is where things get weird. On the emulator everything works fine (app is on 2.1 API, so is the emulator), but when I load it up on my phone, five or more instances of the second activity open at the same time and I have to press back button multiple times to go back to the original screen.

My phone is Samsung i5700 Spica with And 2.3.7 (Cyanogen 7.2 NIGHTLY alpha)

Comment: Have you tried working with View.OnClickListener instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting multiple `onTouch()` events. Verify this through the debugger. on the emulator it's quite boolean, but on a real touch screen in the micro seconds as your finger is coming in contact with the screen you can receive multiple touch events.

If you can use a higher-level function like `onClick` instead of `onTouch`, do that. If you can't you need to keep track of the touch down and touch up events and only react to down if it wasn't already down.

A hack would be to define your activity as single instance, then you won't get multiple instances. This is almost certainly not the right thing to do though.

As a side note, putting `Thread.sleep()` in your code almost always indicates a lurking bug, and that the code is written incorrectly. If you need something to happen at a later point in your code, use `Handler.postDelayed()` or a `Timer`.